# JavaScript concat/merge 2 different objects, both containing arrays for each string

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, concatenation

I want to concat 2 objects into the first object, but making sure the array elements stay in the same x-positions, like:
object.name[x],
object.age[x].

Also, I don't want any duplicates to be overwritten. Every entry should be preserved.

```
var users = {
    name   : [joe , tim],
    age    : [20  , 21]
}

var usersTemp = {
    name   : [bob , joe],
    age    : [22  , 23]
}
```

Result should be saved into (expand) the existing 'users' object:

```
var users = {
    name   : [joe , tim , bob , joe],
    age    : [20  , 21  , 22  , 23 ]
}
```

PS: I'm new to javascript, and since I cant find any examples I am wondering if this approach even makes sense? The list is SUPER long (over 50k entries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to achieve this task if you don't want to append in the original array.

```js
var users = {
  name: ["joe", "tim"],
  age: [20, 21],
};

var usersTemp = {
  name: ["bob", "joe"],
  age: [22, 23],
};

const result = {
  name: [...users.name, ...usersTemp.name],
  age: [...users.age, ...usersTemp.age],
};
console.log(result);
```

If you want to add in the same array then assign the result in the same variable `users`

```js
var users = {
  name: ["joe", "tim"],
  age: [20, 21],
};

var usersTemp = {
  name: ["bob", "joe"],
  age: [22, 23],
};

users = {
  name: [...users.name, ...usersTemp.name],
  age: [...users.age, ...usersTemp.age],
};
console.log(users);
```

If there are multiple properties in both object that need to merge

```js
var users = {
  name: ["joe", "tim"],
  age: [20, 21],
};

var usersTemp = {
  name: ["bob", "joe"],
  age: [22, 23],
};

for (let key in users) {
  users[key].push(...usersTemp[key]);
}

console.log(users);
```

Comment: Thank you! I was trying something similiar, but didn't realize I needed those 3 dots "...", which was giving me weird results.

Comment: Glad I could help you

Answer (score 1):

You could make a function that takes two objects with arbitrary keys and builds your new object with the concatenated values. You can then grab the entries of one of your objects using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), which will give you a `[[key, value], ...]` pair array representation of your object:

```js
[
  ['name', ['joe', 'tim']], // <- inner key-value pair  array
  ['age', [20, 21]]
]
```

Using this array, you can then use the [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method on it, to convert each inner key-value pair into a new key-value pair array, where the key remains, but the value is a concatenated version of the current array value with its corresponding array value from the other object you want to merge with. Once you have your modified the entries array, you can use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) on this array to build your new object from the entries array:

```js
const users = { name: ['joe', 'tim'], age: [20, 21] };
const usersTemp = { name: ['bob', 'ted'], age: [22, 23] };

function concatObjVals(obj1, obj2) {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj1).map(([key, arr]) => [
      key,
      arr.concat(obj2[key])
    ])
  );
}

console.log(concatObjVals(users, usersTemp));
```

This could be written in a more  concise manner if you use arrow-functions:

```js
const concatObjVals = (obj1, obj2) =>
  Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj1).map(([key, arr]) => [key, arr.concat(obj2[key])]));
```

If you find it easier to understand, you can use a regular `for..in` loop instead of `Object.entries()` and `.map()` to build your new object. The below `for..in` loop will iterate through all the keys in your first object (ie: users), and add that key to a new object `result`. It will also set the value to be the current value of the key from the first object, concatenated with the array value from the second object for the current key:

```js
const users = { name: ['joe', 'tim'], age: [20, 21] }; 
const usersTemp = { name: ['bob', 'ted'], age: [22, 23] };

function concatObjVals(obj1, obj2) {
  const result = {};
  for(const key in obj1) {
    result[key] = obj1[key].concat(obj2[key]);
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(concatObjVals(users, usersTemp));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var users = {
    name   : ['joe' , 'tim'],
    age    : [20  , 21]
}

var usersTemp = {
    name   : ['bob' , 'joe'],
    age    : [22  , 23]
}

usersTemp.name.push(...users.name)
usersTemp.age.push(...users.age)

console.log(usersTemp)

// output
// { name: Array ["bob", "joe", "joe", "tim"], age: Array [22, 23, 20, 21] }
```